# WhatsApp Inline Buttons

Tags: button, whatsapp

How do we send inline buttons on WhatsApp similar to one in the attached image. I know we can do that on Telegram but was wondering how this was possible on WhatsApp.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally WhatsApp has launched the API for inline buttons.